# How to convert from XslTransform of VS2003 to XslCompiledTransform of VS2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, xmlreader, xpathdocument

We are currently converting our project from `VS2003` to `VS2005` and I'm looking for the right way to convert the code using  `XslTransform` to `XslCompiledTransform`.

The changing the class name is not the big deal, but when it comes to using
`XslCompiledTransform's` Transform method, I have a problem.

Before `XslTransform's` Transform method was accepting `XPathDocument` object and right now `Transfrom` method expect `XmlReader` instead:

Here is the code:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(DS.GetXml().ToString()));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xslt.Transform(doc,null,sw,null);
```

Also, new `Transform` method expect `System.Xml.XmlWriter` instead of `System.IO.StringWriter`.

What is the best way to fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw.aspx) describes the differences between the XslCompiledTransform and the XslTransform classes.

A [section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has also some code samples in both versions.